# Unity 3D Vive Focus conversion difficulties

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I Keep getting this error message below when I try to build and run the game. I have downloaded sdk package:        sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip Android studio. I am new to this kinda technology any help will be appreciated. The VR device is Vive Focus.

error Message below:
Extracting from
com.htc.vr.samples.hellovr.unity manifest:

miniWaveSDKVersion is Null!
NumDoFHmd is Null!
NumDoFController is Null!
NumController is Null!

Please ensure that these metadata in your 
manifest matches the capabilities of your title.
This metadata will affect how viveport store distributes and displays your title

[image]

[image]